# Save Images on Canvas to File in SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas

From what I've seen on SO, what I want to do is difficult if even possible, but I hope that someone can at least suggest a less roundabout way of doing what I want.  The code below draws items onto a canvas, all within a custom SurfaceView.  What I want to do is, in addition to displaying the canvas, save everything on it to a file for use in a couple of activities, but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
public void draw()
{
    if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
        drawSurface(canvas);
        canvas.translate(-56, 30);
        int i = 0;
        for(Picture a: accessories) {
            canvas.translate(0, a_offset[i]);
            if(a!=null) {
                canvas.drawPicture(a);
            }
            i++;
        }           
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);  
    }
}

private void drawSurface(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.set(37*screenWidth/480, 146*screenHeight/800, (37 + 300)*screenWidth/480, (146 + 300)*screenHeight/800);
    canvas.drawBitmap(avatar, null, rect, null);
}
```

What I'm currently doing to save the file is essentially using copies of the methods above with a Canvas created from a bitmap (`canvas = new Canvas(bitmap)` instead of `holder.lockCanvas`) and with different numbers to get the positions and sizes correct.  I could combine the methods and give them some parameters at least to avoid having different methods, but I'd like to just draw the images and save the file using the same canvas, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be storing the canvas. You should be storing the image transformation matrix and the image itself. Then if you want to retrieve, load the image, load its matrix, apply the matrix to the image and you should be fine.

Or you could try storing the canvas object itself as blob data and then try to recreate it from the database using the blob. I've never done this though and wouldn't recommend it in any case.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear--I don't want to store the canvas, just the image (and the transformation matrix, if I need it).  Can you give me more detail on how to do that?  It doesn't seem easy to do with a Canvas created from lockCanvas.

Comment: check out this method (getMatrix()), which you can call on the canvas object : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getMatrix()

Comment: So that apparently gets me the matrix, but how am I storing my image?  I just want a png with everything I drew onto the canvas.